# Creating single pattern for ${n} type and {{coinsadded}} type of variable so that it can be found in a string

Tags: java, regex

I have different types of regex which can be present in a string. 
For ex:

```
1. ${n}
2. {{coinsAdded}}
3. ${coinsAdded}, etc.
```

I have to create a pattern so that i can find all types of regex present in the string. Can someone please try  to help me out.

I have already created one pattern -

```
\$\\{[a-zA-Z]*+\\}
```

but this  only satisfies my need for regex like 1 and 3, but it fails for 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. What i did was i created Enum for both these regex and then calling any one which is required at that point. This is a better approach since if there are other regex which is present so we can directly add it in the enum itself.

Answer (score 1):

Update thanks to @Spara for pointing out missing

```
(?:\${)[a-zA-Z]+(?:})|(?:\${{)[a-zA-Z]+(?:}})|(?:{{)[a-zA-Z]+(?:}})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Gdm6O/6)

**You can try this**

```
\$?{{?[a-zA-Z]*}}?
```

> Explanation

- `\$?` - Will match `$` (`?` makes it optional ).
- `{{?` - Will match `{` or `{{`.
- `[a-zA-Z]*` - will match any character from a to z zero or more time.
- `}}?` - Will match `}` or `}}`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Gdm6O/3)

Comment: i guess what you provide is working perfectly for php and when trying it for java, its giving error.

Comment: @AnshulSrivastava you need to use escape character properly for java.

Comment: Its not correct, It will match for example this one: `{asdfa}}`

Comment: @Spara yes you're right thanks for pointing out.will rectify this.

Comment: sry I mean second part is maybe extra. also change `[a-zA_Z]` to `[a-zA-Z]` pls

Comment: It seems that you should add another part for `{n}` that is not supporting yet

Comment: Or maybe it's not needed :D. just ask the author

Comment: `${n}
{{coinsAdded}}
${coinsAdded}` yeah op didn't specified.

Comment: @Spara vote up for being so generous :) happy to see people like you on SO :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is working after doing some editing.

Comment: @AnshulSrivastava if it helped you can upvote and mark as correct answer :p anyways happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest* regex I can think of would be:

```
\\$?(\\{[a-zA-Z]+}|\\{\\{[a-zA-Z]+}})
```

* In a "easiest to understand" sense, not in a "most compact" sense.

`\\$?` matches an optional `$`. After which, follows `\\(` one of:
`\\{[a-zA-Z]+}`, i.e. a regex using a single pair of `{}`,
`|` OR,
`\\{\\{[a-zA-Z]+}}` a regex using a double `{{}}`.

Test:

```
System.out.println("{n}".matches("\\$?(\\{[a-zA-Z]+}|\\{\\{[a-zA-Z]+}})"));
System.out.println("{{coinsAdded}}".matches("\\$?(\\{[a-zA-Z]+}|\\{\\{[a-zA-Z]+}})"));
System.out.println("${coinsAdded}".matches("\\$?(\\{[a-zA-Z]+}|\\{\\{[a-zA-Z]+}})"));
System.out.println("{{{coinsAdded}}}".matches("\\$?(\\{[a-zA-Z]+}|\\{\\{[a-zA-Z]+}})"));
System.out.println("$${coinsAdded}".matches("\\$?(\\{[a-zA-Z]+}|\\{\\{[a-zA-Z]+}})"));
```

Output:

> true
>   true
>   true
>   false
>   false

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It didnt work because in both case $ was coming. So i changed it and now it is working. Thanks

Comment: This regex works with or without $ as shown in the test, what do you mean that it didn't work?